# Read file made by another app

Tags: android, file, file-io

An application makes a file in `data/data/package.name/file.txt`. Is there a way for me to open that file from another application (with different package)?
I tried reading the file the standard way (`FileInputStream`), but I get `EACCES error (no permission)`.
Can I maybe copy the file (withouth opening it) to root directory and then open it?

EDIT: What about changing permission of the file withouth root access?

Answer (score 1):

By default, every Android application is able to access the files belonging to its own package only. This means your applications can only read files underneath the package with your package.name. If you try to read other files, you will get an *access denied* exception. This is Android's security model.

One exception is when another application stored its files using [MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) or [MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE) flags, then every other application will be able to access (read or read & write) them. This option is deprecated in API level 17 and higher though.

Comment: I know this. I can't create the file using MODE_WORLD_READABLE because I don't have access to the app source code. I would just like to acess it from my application. Is there a way?

Comment: This is only possible on rooted phones. On standard phones you won't be able to do this because of Android / Linux security. You app runs with its own permissions and they are not enough to read files of another app stored in internal memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably correct, you just need to add an extra `/` (or `File.separator`) before the file name as follows:

```
//Set desired file path. For example:-

File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/new.xml");

try {
  //Read file
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("IOException", "exception while reading file",
            e);
}
```

Also the other applications must have set its data as readable with the appropriate permission.